# Abstract data types vs. data structures for Python

Tags: python

The way I understand it, you use data structures to implement abstract data types.

Am I correct in saying that you can implement stacks, queues, dictionaries, and tuples with lists? If so, does this mean that stacks, queues, dictionaries, and tuples are ADTs and lists are data structures?

Are strings also ADTs that are implemented by a list of chars?

And how are lists implemented in Python? In Java, you need to implement a List interface with LinkedList or ArrayList, etc. But in Python, it seems you can just straight up use a list like an int or an array in Java.

Comment: abstract data types are just a cluster of properties that we are interested in...

Comment: Regarding lists implementation see https://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#how-are-lists-implemented.  Other than that there is the source. The word abstract is overloaded and confusing. In regard to data types it may mean defined at a level where no implementation decision is visible.  This is especially relevant in object oriented languages because the concept of object separates visibility from existence - going back to Nick Wirth in the modula3 days.  See http://www.pasteur.fr/formation/infobio/python/ch19s03.html for a discussion on ADTs.